# Has the effect of magnetic fields on time ever been examined experimentally?

Tags: special-relativity, magnetic-fields, time

Relativity of time can be examined with satellites as gravitational or acceleration. Is there any similar experiment with intense magnetic fields?

Comment: Many particle accelerators employ huge magnetic fields. If the fields affected time then it would affect the life-time of the particles which is something that would be observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment Kyle points out the question [Does strong magnetic field cause time dilation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100279/does-strong-magnetic-field-cause-time-dilation), which is closely related to your question. However it isn't a duplicate because you are specifically asking whether experiments have been done, not whether the effect theoretically exists.

Theoretically we would expect a magnetic fied to contribute to the curvature of spacetime, and therefore to cause time dilation. This is not anything special about magnetic fields, any form of stored energy will have the same effect. I confess I do not know how to write the stress-energy tensor for a magnetic field - perhaps one of the more experienced general relativists hereabouts can comment.

However, for any magnetic fields mankind can generate the effect is going to be immeasurably small. You mention the time dilation measured by GPS satellites, but this is a tiny effect. The clocks on the GPS satellites run fast by about by only about 38 microseconds per day, and this is with the whole mass of the Earth ($5.97 \times 10^{24}$ kg!) contributing to the bending of spacetime. The amount of energy we can get into even our strongest magnetic fields is utterly insignificant compared to the mass of the Earth, and their effects on the spacetime curvature will also be insignificant.

So the answer to your question is that no, the experiments have not been done because no-one expects them to produce a measurable effect. As Lemon mentions in a comment, strong magnetic fields are used in many areas of physics, and any big effect on elapsed time woukld have been noticed by now.

Comment: @BurtayMutlu: hi Burtay. If you think this answers the question please click on the tick symbol to accept it.