# General relativity

Tags: general-relativity, magnetic-fields, spacetime, curvature

Does an object without magnetic field curve space-time? In another word, can an object with magnetic field bend space-time more? Or curvature of space-time only depends on the mass of objects?

Comment: see the stress-energy tensor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do strong magnetic fields cause time dilation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100279/)

Answer (score 1):

According to general relativity it is the mass/energy of an object that curves space-time. Since a magnetic field has energy, then it also is responsible for the amount of space-time curvature that an object causes.

Comment: Lewis, I'm wondering if this is correct.   We have created some darned powerful magnets, but I've never heard of a magnet picking up a piece of wood - no matter how small.  Has there ever been any evidence of this other than the basic GR theory?

Comment: Then the Reissner-Nordström metric must be a joke. A non-zero momentum energy tensor has a clear impact on the metric of the space-time, which in turn means more curvature. This can be explained through the energy-momentum relation, through which the energy of the magnetic field contributes to the final mass of the object. Therefore it is very intuitive that wood has not been observed to move because of a magnet because the total mass of the magnet plus the energy from the field is still extremely small.